# Не могу понять - mysql не так выдает результаты LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT shop_items.id FROM shop_items
LEFT JOIN shop_items_rows_values as row10 on row10.id_row='10' and row10.id_item=shop_items.id 
where (row10.value = '19' or row10.value = '24') and archive = '0'
```

Результат выдает shop_items с row10.value и 20 и 16...

Таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `division` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `divisions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `art` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `images` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_items_rows_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_row` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN выбирает **все** строки из левой таблицы. И к ним - соответствующие строки из правой таблицы, или null, если таких строк нет.

Т.е. ваш код выбирает все строки из shop_items. Даже те, у которых в правой таблице нет соответствий.

Если нужны только shop_items c row10.value 19 и 24 - поменяйте на INNER JOIN.